# ActionFilter not being called WebAPI/.netCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, action-filter

I have a web API app written in .NETCore and all I want is to intercept the request using an action filter and then validate the JWT token in the from the header. I Have written an ActionFilter which looks like the following:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Applciation.ActionFilters
{
    public class AuthorizeJWT: ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var jwt = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["JWT"];

            try
            {
                var json = new JwtBuilder()
                    .WithSecret(File.ReadLines("").ToList().First())
                    .MustVerifySignature()
                    .Decode(jwt);                    

                var tokenDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            }
            catch (TokenExpiredException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Token is expired");
            }
            catch (SignatureVerificationException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Token signature invalid");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
              throw new Exception("Token has been tempered with");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I added the action filter in services config like below:

`services.AddScoped<AuthorizeJWT>();`

and decorated my controller like below:

```
 [AuthorizeJWT]            
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Ceate([FromBody]CreateDto,createDto)
{
   //method body
}
```

But for some reason, my action filter is just not being called. Is there anything that I am missing from the configuration?

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel?  This can be done using the `[Authorize]` attribute and setting up `JwtBearer` authentication.

Comment: As above commenter said, Asp.net Core has already JWT, you just configure it: https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/asp-net-core-2-0-webapi-jwt-authentication-with-identity-mysql-3698eeba6ff8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of your `ActionFilter` is incorrect. You only need to derive from the `ActionFilterAttribute` class and not the interface `IActionFilter` as the ActionFilterAttribute class already implements that interface.

If you remove the interface from the inheritance and then change your `OnActionExecuting` method definition to override the base class implementation then everything will work as expected:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Applciation.ActionFilters
{
    public class AuthorizeJWT: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var jwt = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["JWT"];

            try
            {
                var json = new JwtBuilder()
                    .WithSecret(File.ReadLines("").ToList().First())
                    .MustVerifySignature()
                    .Decode(jwt);                    

                var tokenDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            }
            catch (TokenExpiredException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Token is expired");
            }
            catch (SignatureVerificationException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Token signature invalid");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
              throw new Exception("Token has been tempered with");
            }
        }
    }
}
```